# Android Emulator: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, flutter

When I select a Web chrome device and run flutter application it works, but when I select Android device and run flutter the build fails

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find apksig-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/4.1.0/apksig-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find annotations-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/27.1.0/annotations-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-4.1.0.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/4.1.0/databinding-common-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/4.1.0/baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: you need to upload file project/build.gradle and app/project.gradle. I need to check these 2 files because I thing maybe you are configuring data binding is missing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70224989/16057687

Answer (score 0):

Go to ADB manager and Wipe the data of your emulator than run the emulator it works fine

Comment: I try that but not work