# when i select a web chrome device and run flutter app is work but when i select android device and run not work?

Tags: android, flutter

it cause problem
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find apksig-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/4.1.0/apksig-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find annotations-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/27.1.0/annotations-27.1.0.jar
> Could not find databinding-common-4.1.0.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/4.1.0/databinding-common-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/4.1.0/baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.untitled3"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
   project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
   project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

   task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: If you want to regenerate the android directory, delete it and run `flutter create .`